# Send notification from Android app to Facebook with link to download

Tags: android, facebook, notifications

I am developing an Android app that is supposed to be able to send notifications to other Facebook friends with a link to a page to download the app.

I have been using the RequestDialog from Facebook but every time I open the notification  in Facebook I get this error message :

"The page you requested cannot be displayed right now. It may be temporarily unavailable, the link you clicked on may be broken or expired, or you may not have permission to view this page"

This is the code I have been using.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("message", "Learn how to make your Android apps social");


    WebDialog requestsDialog = (
            new WebDialog.RequestsDialogBuilder(this,
                    Session.getActiveSession(),
                    params))
            .setOnCompleteListener(new WebDialog.OnCompleteListener() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                                       FacebookException error) {
                    if (error != null) {
                        if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Request cancelled",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Network Error",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        final String requestId = values.getString("request");
                        if (requestId != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Request sent",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Request cancelled",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }

            })
            .build();
    requestsDialog.show();
```

Where can I put a link to download my app?

Comment: are you done with the required settings in Facebook app developer console ?

Comment: If you are referring to the options in the Native Android App category then yes. I haven't done anything else in the Facebook app developer console. The package name should be path to the class that uses the Facebook login, right?

Comment: yeah.You also need to enable Deep Linking and Facebook Login both. Also you need to set the  key Hash.

Comment: You do not need to enable deep linking for the dialogs to work. Is your session opened and non-null?